# How to create a object of unlimited dynamic 2D Array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I know how to create an object of 2D "Static size" array in C# using `string[,] wordDBArray = new string[5,5]` .... but my problem is how to create an object of "Dynamic size" 2D array (i mean without initializing like [5,5] ).. please help me... thanks

Comment: Look into `System.Collections`...specifically, `List<String>`:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.aspx  and  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx

Comment: Arrays are not dynamic. If you need a dynamic container, use something from IList

Comment: As pointed out by Tom, this is what Lists are for.

Comment: @user2456925 - The answer to your question is you cannot have an `Array` of unlimited size.  An `Array` is not dynamic and even if it were it could not be of an unlimited size.  There are size restrictions to every object to take into consideration.  **This seems like a poorly researched question.**

Answer (score 3):

Try using a `List<T>`, or more specifically, a `List<List<string>>`.

Here's how you'd do it:

```
List<List<string>> myList = Enumerable.Repeat(new List<string>(), 5).ToList();
```

And you use it slightly differently. Instead of indexing like `[x,y]`, you index like `[x][y]`.

The only problem is that they are jagged, so what can happen is that you have something like this:

```
{1, 2, 3}
{1, 2, 3, 4}
{1, 2}
```

while an array guarantees that they'll all have the same length.